# Css - Padding being totally ignored, white space appear where it should not

Tags: css

I have a simple error, below is the adress you can visit to see the issue at hand.

Why is parts of the header white? It's set to be a light shade of green, and to it should be placed the the very top (beneath the topmenu) and after that the 60px margin-top on #menu should push it down into it's correct position and making the entire area green.

This is what isn't happening, and I cannot for the life of me understand why. I removed the margin-top and it only pushed the div up, but how can I then place the menu in it's correct position ( I should add that the menu with login etc, is placed correctly but it's just that unknown white gap that's the problem)

-- Removed Adress as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margin-top that you're adding to #menu is what is causing that gap.

Comment: there is no element #menu inside the dom-tree

Comment: Yes there is. body > #wrapper > #header > #menu

Comment: #menu { margin-top: 60px !important; } ==> <div id="menu">

Comment: This would be useful if you atleast had pointed me in the direction to a solution, just saying something doesn't work is not helpful.

Besides, how should I place it otherwise? I could use position aboslute I guess, but that seems like alot of extra bytes (Yes, I'm conservative)

The margin to the div should enlarge the parent div, that's not happening though.

Comment: I explained why it's happening. You didn't ask for a solution. But you can remove the margin-top from #menu and transfer it over to #wrapper. But I would also remove the !important and change the value to 34px.

Comment: @Hultin - interesting approach - you asked what the unknown reason was, it is now known.

Comment: It seems I explained myself utterly poorly, I will edit main post to be more accurate

Comment: @Hultin that's just not how margin works. If you use margin-top on the top most child element it will leak out the top of the parent. If you want it to push the child down, you could use padding-top on the parent.

Comment: @Hultin if you provided a comp of what you're attempting to get the layout to look like, I could provide a more detailed and complete solution. However, SO isn't the place to have others do your work. We can explain why something is misbehaving though.

Comment: Ok, I seem to have misunderstood how the margin attribute works. Thank you Arrayknight for your help. 

I also want to point out that I DO understand this isn't a place to have others do my work. But I'm sure you have at some point been frustrated to the point of boling and felt that you've tried it all.

I've worked it out now with your first @hultin post however.

Answer (score 0):

just add an top margin to your #wrapper

position: fixed
sets your element on a fixed position with the standard behaviour for other elements to ignore this element anymore in fact your fixed element will overlay everything else, because it's not bound anymore to other elements and all elements after your fixed box will ignore the bounding box.

Comment: This sadly does not explain why it completly and utterly ignore this
    margin-top:60px !important;

Answer (score 0):

The content_background element has CSS property padding-top set to 10px. Remove that and it should be OK.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have expressed the issue incorrectly. The gap I refered to was the gap between the topmenu and the lighter shade green in the header